# Express (express_generator) on Windows runs a file named simply express, NOT express.js

Tags: express

This may not be a problem, but I noticed that, when issuing the command  >express   at the Command Prompt (in Windows 10) the file that is actually run is \node_modules\express-generator\bin\express, NOT the \node_modules\express\lib\express.js  code. I understand that node doesn't actually need a .js extension, but I am accustomed to the distinction between the bundled linux batch files (which also show no extensions on my system) and a windows batch file which has the extension .cmd, and this made me wonder about the validity of the version of express that I downloaded. In their new approach using express_generator, are they just supplying the one javascript file for both Windows and Linux? Did I get the correct one? 
. . .
By the way, the express file in question does indeed have one of those shebang lines at top, specifically, #!/usr/bin/env node. That certainly implies that the file has been tailored to Linux. Of course, shebang lines would simply be ignored on windows, but it does give one pause.
. . .
Thanks for any assistance

Comment: Indeed I have this problem, trying to solve it but this does not work this my operating system.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: everything looks okay.

`express\lib\express.js` is part of the Express module, it's the actual code that a developer uses to develop an Express application. This file isn't not used directly from the command line.

`express-generator\bin\express` is the command line tool that the `express-generator` provides to create Express project directories. This is meant to be run from the command line.

On Linux/Unix, command line tools generally don't have an extension (something that you already mention). These tools can be implemented using any number of different programming languages, including Javascript. Linux knows which interpreter to use to run the tool using the shebang line.

I don't know about the internals of Windows, so not sure how it handles those extensionless command line tools, but as long as `express` (the CLI tool) works, I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: I wasn't really worried. I was just wondering about all these subfolder structures. I just find it interesting that sometimes - especially in a module subfolder - they will add the .js extension, but at other times they don't. They're probably just sure that it will work on both platforms in those cases. Thanks immensely for the response.

Comment: @Tallisfan the general rule of thumb is that files that are meant to be run as command line scripts don't have an extension, and files that are intended to be used programmatically do.

Comment: Perhaps that is the policy, but it certainly is not followed on Windows, where the .cmd extension is commonly used.

Comment: @Tallisfan I forgot to mention that that general rule of thumb applies to Unix-like OS'es :) As an aside, isn't the `.cmd` specifically used for batch files?

Comment: Yes, .cmd is the alternative to .bat